# Finding intersection of row space and column space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}-5&6&10&1\\-5&8&10&1\\-21&21&40&4\\6&1&-10&-1\end{pmatrix}$$What is $W\cap U$ where $W$ is the row space of $A$ and $U$ is the column space of $A$.

I have already found that $$W=\text{Sp}\left\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),\left(0,0,1,\frac{1}{10}\right)\right\} \ , \ U=\text{Sp}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}-5\\-5\\-21\\6\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}6\\8\\21\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}10\\10\\40\\-10\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
But I don't know how to compute the intersection...

Comment: What you've written doesn't make sense. You mean that $W$ and $U$ are the *spans* of those sets, not the sets themselves.

Comment: @symplectomorphic, you are correct, thanks for pointing that. I have edited.

Comment: I might as well add a hint. One way to do it is determine which of the basis vectors of $U$ are in $W$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic, thanks! you mean I should for example look for some $c_1,c_2,c_3$, such that $c_1w_1+c_2w_2+c_3w_3=u_1$, right?

Comment: no! since you know the span of $W$ is made of those 3 vectors, just put in the first of $U$ and calculate determinant of $4 \times 4$ matrix. Rinse and repeat with the other two.

Comment: No way! In a 4 dimensional space the intersection of 2 spaces of dimension 3 must be at least 2. Thus it is 2 or 3 in this case! To be 3 they must be equal. So if $\det(w_1,w_2,w_3,u_1) \not =0$ the dimension is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One characterisation of the row space over $\mathbb{R}$ is that it is the subspace perpendicular to the kernel of the matrix. Since the kernel is spanned by the vector $$ v = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ -10 \end{matrix} \right)$$ we conclude that intersection $U\cap W$ are exactly the vectors $u\in U$ such that $v^Tu=0$.

Now, you have already calculated the base of $U$ above (we immediately know it is the base because the kernel has dimension 1 and we can use rank-nullity). Let $u_1,u_2,u_3$ denote the above base, then every element $u\in U$ can be written uniquely as $u=\lambda_1u_1+\lambda_2u_2+\lambda_3u_3$ where $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then $u\in U\cap W$ if and only if $0=v^Tu = -81\lambda_1+11\lambda_2+140\lambda_3.$ From this we can conclude that $U\cap W$ has dimension 2 and $\left\{\frac{11}{81}u_1+u_2, \frac{140}{81}u_1+u_3 \right\}$ is a basis for this subspace.

Comment: Why the vectors $u\in U:\, v^Tu=0$ are in $U\cap W$? I understand the computation, but why is that true?

Comment: Because $w\in W$ if and only if $v^Tw=0$.

Comment: I took a whole course linear algebra I still don't understand why what you are saying is true, that is, why is (∈  if and only if ^=0. ) true? @LeonSot